# ELK and Filebeat configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am working with https://www.elastic.co/, I installed Elasticsearch,Logstash,Kibana and Filebeat. I am taking /var/log/*.log in filebeat.yml and configured output to elasticsearch and enabled some modules but i am not getting modules logs, input is loaded but harvester is not started. 
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have a permission issue there.
If you have this error :

```
[WARN ][logstash.inputs.file     ] failed to open /var/log/yum.log: Permission denied - /var/log/yum.log
```

You should consider starting filebeat with a root privilege.